# Problem with Power Series Problem

Tags: calculus

So, I was given this problem:

Let f(x) be the function defined by the power series:
$$1-\frac{1}{3}(x-2)+\frac{1}{9}(x-2)^2-\frac{1}{27}(x-2)^3+...+(-1)^n\frac{(x-2)^n}{3^n}$$

(a) For what values of x does the series converge?

(b)Write the first four terms and the general term of the power series for f ’(x)
centered at x = 2 and find f ’(2).

(c) Write an equation of the tangent line of f(x) at the point where x = 2.

So far, I solved for a:

x - 2 < 3 --> -1 < x < 5

However, I'm struggling with B. So far I've done:
$$f'=0-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}(2x-4)-\frac{(x-2)^2}{9}+\frac{4}{81}(x-2)^3$$

I'm not sure how to find the general term nor do I know where to start with C. Any help?

Comment: General should be $\dfrac{(-1)^n n(x-2)^{n-1}}{3^n}, ~~n\geq 1$

Comment: What you have in the post is a polynomial; your series only has n terms.

Comment: @user1046533 What do I do? To get the first 4 terms for f' I just got the derivative from the original f.

Comment: You should probably fix the statement of your exercise first. As it is stated, the "series" converges for very $x$ because it only has finitely many terms.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you're trying to says
$$1-\frac{1}{3}(x-2)+\frac{1}{9}(x-2)^{2}-\frac{1}{27}(x-2)^{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n}\frac{(x-2)^{n}}{3^{n}}+\cdots$$

Otherwise, if you don't add the points "$+\cdots$"  after the $n$-th term, what you indicate is just a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$, but you're saying about a power series.

Well, notice what we can re-write your series as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}(x-2)^{n}$$
This is a power series with $n-$th term $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}$ and centered at $x=2$.

- By ratio test,
  \begin{align*}
  \rho&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}(x-2)^{n+1} }{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}(x-2)^{n}}\right|,\\&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{|x-2|}{3},\\&=\frac{|x-2|}{3}
  \end{align*}
  Now, consider the cases a) $\rho<1$, b)$\rho>1$ and c) $\rho=1$ for the test the convergence.

> Just a small remark: you need to check all the cases: a), b) and c) in the way to study the interval of convergence for $x$.

- Over the interval of convergence we have,
  $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}(x-2)^{n}$$Hence,$$f'(x)=\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x}=\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}}\color{blue}{n(x-2)^{n-1}}.$$

> Just a small remark: Notice that when calculating the first derivative of $f$, we move the index $1$ unit (in red and yes, if asked for the second derivative, move the index forward by $2$ units, etc.) and also note that the derivative is calculated with respect to $x$ (the color blue) as usual for a derivative of $x^n$.

Then setting $x=2$ you can obtain $f'(2)$.

- Consider the equation
  $$y-y_{0}=f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})$$
  with $x_{0}=2, y_{0}=f(x_{0})=f(2)$ and $f'(x_{0})=f'(0)$ and then find the tangent-line.